# compare regular select and prepared select performace

Tags: c++, mysql, c, mysql-connector

I try to use prepared select for get data from mysql,beacuse I think this faster than regular select.

this is select syntax:

```
char *sql = "select id,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5 from pricelist where d1 > ? limit 1000000";
```

that id,d2,d3 type `unsigned int` and other `__int64`

I wirte my code for prepared like below:

```
stmt = mysql_stmt_init(conn);
mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, sql, strlen(sql));

// Select
param[0].buffer_type     = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
param[0].buffer         = (void *) &myId;
param[0].is_unsigned    = 1;
param[0].is_null        = 0;
param[0].length         = 0;

// Result


result[0].buffer_type     = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
result[0].buffer         = (void *) &id;
result[0].is_unsigned    = 1;
result[0].is_null         = &is_null[0];
result[0].length         = 0;

result[1].buffer_type     = MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG;
result[1].buffer         = (void *) &d1;
result[1].is_unsigned    = 1;
result[1].is_null         = &is_null[0];
result[1].length         = 0;

result[2].buffer_type     = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
result[2].buffer         = (void *) &d2;
result[2].is_unsigned    = 1;
result[2].is_null         = &is_null[0];
result[2].length         = 0;

result[3].buffer_type     = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
result[3].buffer         = (void *) &d3;
result[3].is_unsigned    = 1;
result[3].is_null         = &is_null[0];
result[3].length         = 0;

result[4].buffer_type     = MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG;
result[4].buffer         = (void *) &d4;
result[4].is_unsigned    = 1;
result[4].is_null         = &is_null[0];
result[4].length         = 0;

result[5].buffer_type     = MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG;
result[5].buffer         = (void *) &d5;
result[5].is_unsigned    = 1;
result[5].is_null         = &is_null[0];
result[5].length         = 0;

mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, param);
mysql_stmt_bind_result(stmt, result);
mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);
mysql_stmt_store_result(stmt);
while(mysql_stmt_fetch (stmt) == 0){
}
```

and my code for reqular select is like below:

```
mysql_query(conn,"select id ,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5 from pricebook where us > 12 limit 1000000")
result = mysql_use_result(conn); 
while (mysql_fetch_row(result)){
}
```

I run this two functions from remote pc and check time period for each one,duration for both of then is same equal to 6 sec
and when I check pcap file I see that vol that sent for prepared is same with reqular query even that in prepared comperes data.

```
$ capinfos prepared.pcap regular.pcap
File name:           prepared.pcap
File type:           Wireshark - pcapng
File encapsulation:  Ethernet
Packet size limit:   file hdr: (not set)
Number of packets:   40 k
File size:           53 MB
Data size:           52 MB
Capture duration:    6 seconds
Start time:          Thu Aug 22 09:41:54 2013
End time:            Thu Aug 22 09:42:00 2013
Data byte rate:      8820 kBps
Data bit rate:       70 Mbps
Average packet size: 1278.63 bytes
Average packet rate: 6898 packets/sec
SHA1:                959e589b090e3354d275f122a6fe6fbcac2351df
RIPEMD160:           7db6a437535d78023579cf3426c4d88d8ff3ddc3
MD5:                 888729dc4c09baf736df22ef34bffeda
Strict time order:   True

File name:           regular.pcap
File type:           Wireshark - pcapng
File encapsulation:  Ethernet
Packet size limit:   file hdr: (not set)
Number of packets:   38 k
File size:           50 MB
Data size:           49 MB
Capture duration:    6 seconds
Start time:          Thu Aug 22 09:41:05 2013
End time:            Thu Aug 22 09:41:11 2013
Data byte rate:      7740 kBps
Data bit rate:       61 Mbps
Average packet size: 1268.65 bytes
Average packet rate: 6101 packets/sec
SHA1:                badf2040d826e6b0cca089211ee559a7c8a29181
RIPEMD160:           68f3bb5d4fcfd640f2da9764ff8e9891745d4800
MD5:                 4ab73a02889472dfe04ed7901976a48c
Strict time order:   True
```

if this ok that duration is same or I don't use prepared select as well as?

how I can improve it?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database server executes prepared statements and regular statements with the same speed. The performance difference comes when you execute the same query with different parameters: a prepared statement is parsed and prepared for execution *once* and then can be executed cheaply with different parameters, while a regular statement has to be parsed every time you want to execute it.